# .NET Core + Docker - How to Persist uploaded files in wwwroot after new build

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have an app developped in .Net Core et i use Docker to Deploy it in Linux VPS.

In The app, i have a feature that consists on uploading files and i store them in wwwroot. I have used docker volumes to externalize the folder.

But everytime i did a build i loose all the files that users uploaded. Which is normal..

**Update:** This is how i'm declaring the volume

```
app:
image: app
depends_on:
  - "postgres_image"
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile
ports:
  - "5000:5000"
volumes:
  - app_wwwroot:/wwwroot
```

My question is what is the best approach to be able to make changes on the app (build source code and get a new release) without loosing the uploaded files.

Thanks.

Comment: how did you mount your docker volume? Are you sure the users files are stored in the wwwroot folder?

Comment: @MaartenDev yes users files are stored in wwwroot folder. The build is replacing the folder by an empty one.

Answer (score 0):

It would've been better if you provided how you are using docker volumes to persist the **wwwroot** data.
If you want to persist your data you can either use bind mounts or volumes within the docker run command or the docker-compose.

I usually use bind mounts instead of volumes when I want to persist data:

```sh
docker run -v './path/on/your/machine:/path/inside/the/container' image_name
```

or In docker compose

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: image_name
    volumes:
      - './path/on/your/machine:/path/inside/the/container'
```

as you can see you will be mounting `./path/on/your/machine` from your host machine into `/path/inside/the/container` which is the data of **wwwroot** in your case.

> Any changes made on each one of the dir/file mapped inside the container or your host machine will affect both.

> Building again wouldn't affect the dir/file

Comment: I have updated my post by adding what i'm using to declare volume

Comment: As I can see you are using a volume type `volume`, have you tried to use volume type `bind-mount` instead as stated in my answer?